# How to delete text after it's printed

Tags: python-3.x

I'm working on a poker program, and to keep each player's hand private, I want to incorporate passwords, for example something like:

```
     p1name = input("What would player 1 like to be called? ")
    p1pass = input("Please enter a password to be used to play: ")
    cardvalu = ["Ace of" , "Two of" , "Three of" , "Four of" ,
                "Five of" , "Six of" , "Seven of" , "Eight of" ,
                "Nine of" , "Jack of" , "Queen of" , "King of"]                         #These are the hands that the program will be picking when distributing cards

    cardhand = ["Spades" , "Diamonds" , "Hearts" , "Clubs"]                             #These are the numbers the program will be picking when distributing cards
def p1hand():                                                                            #Next two lines show the cards for Player 1
    print(random.choice(cardvalu),random.choice(cardhand))
    print(random.choice(cardvalu),random.choice(cardhand))
```

However, when the player is asked to enter his password, I realized that someone could just  minimize the graphic and look at everyone's password and hands. So, I'd like to know how to delete a line of text after it's printed after a specified amount of time.

Comment: "someone could just minimize the graphic and look at everyone's password and hands." How is that supposed to work? You need a better description of what you're currently trying to do.

Comment: You can overwrite the line with spaces. But this may also depend on the terminal you're using, or whatever mechanism you're using to show output to a user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the specific case of receiving input without echoing it to the screen, you usually use [`getpass.getpass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/getpass.html#getpass.getpass) instead of `input`, so the user's input isn't echoed in the first place.

Otherwise, you need to deal with moving the cursor around (via ANSI control codes or using [the `curses` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html) to completely take over the terminal) then overwriting what was echoed to the screen with spaces or the like, which is typically more annoying.